# Is there a way to quickly toggle "per rest" in the AI script?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

The Pillars of Eternity AI script settings have a toggle for "use per-rest abilities". I generally have two situations: 1) don't waste resources, or 2) big battle. There doesn't appear to be any way to switch this except by going into each character's setting dialog, checking or unchecking, and making sure to hit "save". Is there a way I'm overlooking which will toggle this switch for the whole party?

Comment: Did you ever figure out any more details?